# How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n-i}{k}=0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove that: 
\begin{equation*}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n-i}{k}=0;~k\geq0 ; n\geq1. 
\end{equation*}
Can any one help me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: For $i \leqslant n-k$, fiddle a bit with $\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{k}$ to get it into a shape that you know.

Comment: just a quick check:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^1 (-1)^i \binom{1}{i} \binom{1-i}{1}&=(-1)^0 \binom{1}{0} \binom{1-0}{1}+(-1)^1 \binom{1}{1} \binom{1-1}{1}\\ 
&=1
\end{align}

Comment: @Math-fun, it looks like the correct conditions are $0\le k\lt n$ instead of $k\ge0;n\ge1$.

Comment: Thanks, this could be helpful to OP too.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here's a generating function answer.  Fix $k \geq 0$ and let $a_n = (-1)^n$ and $b_n = \binom{n}{k}$.  Letting $a$ and $b$ be the exponential generating functions for these sequences, then
\begin{align*}
a(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} = e^{-x}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
b(x) &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq k} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq k} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq k} \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!} x^n\\
&= \frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{n \geq k} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} x^{n-k} = \frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{j \geq 0} \frac{1}{j!} x^{j} = \frac{x^k}{k!} e^x
\end{align*}
where we have made the change of index $j = n-k$.  By the convolution formula for exponential generating functions, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-1)^i \binom{n-i}{k} &= \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] a(x) b(x) = \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] e^{-x} \frac{x^k}{k!} e^{x}\\
&= \left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right] \frac{x^k}{k!} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \ n=k\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right]$ is the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in the formal series.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:
$$\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{k}=\dfrac{n!}{i!\,(n-i)!}\cdot\dfrac{(n-i)!}{k!\,(n-i-k)!}=\dfrac{n!}{i!\,k!\,(n-i-k)!}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{i}$$

Comment: now i know that $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n}{k} x^{n-k}y^k$  with x=1 and y = -1 i get $(1-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n}{k} (-1)^k$ and let n=n-k: $(1-1)^{n-k}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom {n-k}{i} (-1)^i$. is this the correct way and how can i combine the both sums to get it ?

Comment: @Noah $$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{i}=\binom{n}{k}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\binom{n-k}{i}\right)$$$$=\binom{n}{k}(1-1)^{n-k}=0$$

Comment: @Noah Also note that even in the first term the sum should run from $i=0$ to $i=n-k$, since $\binom{n-i}{k}=0$ when $n-i<k$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a  solution using complex variables that  involves only finite
sums.

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$S_k(n) = \sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^q {n\choose q} {n-q\choose k}.$$

Introduce
$${n-q\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-q}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q 
\frac{(1+z)^{n-q}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q 
\frac{1}{(1+z)^q} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}
\frac{z^n}{(1+z)^n} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1-n}} \; dz.$$

This is zero by inspection except when $k+1-n=1$ or $k=n$
when it evaluates to one.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected HINT: For $k=0$ you can verify it by direct calculation; note that here you really do need $n>0$. As noted in the comments, the result is false for $k=n$. For $k>0$ show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}i\binom{n-i}k$$

is an [inclusion-exclusion calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) of the number of subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $k$ that contain every element of $[n]$; since there are clearly no such sets when $k<n$, this will prove that in those cases the sum is $0$.

Comment: How do you reconcile this with Math-fun's comment?

Comment: @Barry: I mentally inverted what was happening; it should be okay now. Thanks for drawing my attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that only when $n \neq k$, the equation holds.

When $n = k$, $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i{n \choose i}{n - i \choose k} = {n \choose 0}{n \choose n} = 1$.

When $n > k$, besides Demosthene's hint, I give another hint below.

$$
(1 - x)^{n-k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}{n -k \choose i}(-1)^i x^i
$$

The case for $n < k$ is trivial.