# Binomial coefficient identities from h-vector of a simplicity complex.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, simplicial-complex, algebraic-combinatorics

My question is to show the below equality

$$\sum_{j=0}^{d}(-1)^{j}\binom{d}{j}\binom{d-j}{i}=0$$
when $d>i \geq 0$ for any integers $d,i$.

This inequality is came from [Stanley's note](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/34.pdf). Given an $f$-vector of a simplicial complex $\Delta$ with dimension $d-1=\dim \Delta$, $(f_0,\cdots,f_{d-1},0,\cdots)$, define a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by sending $m$ to

$$H(\Delta,m):=1 \text{ if }m=0 \text{ or } \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}f_{i}\binom{m-1}{i} \text{ otherwise}.$$
Then, he claims that the series
$$(1-\lambda)^{d}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}H(\Delta,m)\lambda^{m}$$
as a notation $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}h_{i}\lambda^{i}$ is indeed a polynomial with $h_{k}=0$ for all $k>d$. Since he said $h_{k}=0$ is easily seen, I try to recover it and stucked..

What I'm try to do is following; notes that when $k>d$,
$$h_{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{d}(-1)^{j}\binom{d}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}f_{i}\binom{k-j-1}{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}f_{i}\sum_{j=0}^{d}(-1)^{j}\binom{d}{j}\binom{k-j-1}{i}.$$
And, indeed, by the pascal's formula and induction, it suffices to show that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{d}(-1)^{j}\binom{d}{j}\binom{d-j}{i}=0$$
for all $i<d$. Also, $i=0$ is just trivial; however, I don't know how to show it when $i>0$. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n-i}{k}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298234/how-to-prove-sum-limits-i-0n-1i-binomni-binomn-ik-0). Note this was found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bd%7D(-1)%5E%7Bj%7D%5Cbinom%7Bd%7D%7Bj%7D%5Cbinom%7Bd-j%7D%7Bi%7D%3D0%24&p=1). Note Barry Cipra's question [comment](/questions/1298234/how-to-prove-sum-limits-i-0n-1i-binomni-binomn-ik-0?noredirect=1#comment2636517_1298234) there states that question requires $0 \le k \lt n$.

Comment: It looks like an inclusion-exclusion formula. Let $A$ be all the subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,d\}$ of size $i,$ and $A_k$ be the subset of them that do not contain $k.$ The the formula computes the inclusion-exclusion formula for the size of $A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_d).$ which is zero unless $i=d.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews FYI, your comment's concept is related to what Brian M. Scott's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1298246/602049) uses in my proposed duplicate.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you very much for letting me know the post. I need to search more.